# Conditional expectation with 2 events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Using the definition of conditional expectation given an event I need to show

$$ E (I_B | A) = P(B|A).$$

So far I have

\begin{align*}
E (I_B | A) &= \sum_x 1\cdot P(I_B = 1 |A) P(A) + 0 \cdot P(I_B = 0|A)P(A) \\
&= \sum_x P(I_B = 1 | A) P(A) \\
&= \sum_x P(B | A) P(A) \\
&= P(B|A).
\end{align*}

I feel like there is something I am missing here. I was hoping somebody could better explain to me how to work on conditioning with two events. My book doesn't go into much detail on the matter, only addresses the case with one event.

Comment: In the first line of the derivation, you multiplied both terms by $P(A)$.  Why?  If you leave it out, your derivation is fine.

Comment: Also, there shouldn't be a sum over $x$, as $x$ doesn't appear in the summands; you've already written out the sum $\sum_x\mathsf xP(I_B=x\mid A)$ with the two summands for $x=0$ and $x=1$.